# How Do I decrease a background-image opacity if I directly linked the image url from google?

Tags: css

I'm trying to decrease the background opacity, but since I directly linked the image from google, it's not working properly.

```
.form {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(84, 58, 231), rgb(91, 27, 240));
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 16px;
  padding: 120px 50px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #8888888f;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/07/03/18/04/tech-1495181_1280.jpg");
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

the opacity decreases the entire .form section including the form inputs/text/ and image.

I'm trying to only decrease the background image opacity, so the background linear gradient I have will still show over the background image

I ended up making it work by adding a new empty div tag with the class img-overlay, then I added this code to the css

```
.img-overlay {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/07/03/18/04/tech-1495181_1280.jpg");
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-12.5%, -20%);
  opacity: 0.2;
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: you can't. CSS doesn't handle background image opacity.

But what you can do, is adding a pseudo-element being an image with opacity, or using an actual element being either `<img>` or another element with `background-image` and `opacity`.

```css
.some-element:before {
    content: url('https://i.picsum.photos/id/1/1440/900.jpg');
    opacity: 0.5;
    /* some other properties of your image */
}
```

Comment: I tried that earlier, but it didn't show my image for some reason. Only showed the original .form css. Here's what i added, but doesn't show my image. 


`.form:before {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/07/03/18/04/tech-1495181_1280.jpg");
  opacity: 0.5;
}`

Comment: It doesn't work, because you need `content` property for a pseudoelement to appear, even `content: ''` will work. But you will need to also set `width` and `height` for your pseudo-element if you want to apply the background. That's why I used `content: url(...)` instead, as it works more like an `<img>`.

Comment: so the only other alternative would be to save the img to a folder, then add the img to my html?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the image being external or local. Do you want that image to cover entire form?

Comment: yeah basically have it as a background with a super light opacity, so you can barely see it. Just want it to blend in with my current background color

Comment: Yeah, so you need another element to do that, the only problem is to properly size and position it.

Comment: I tried to add the img to the html and then target it in the css, but for some reason my entire form inputs went blank?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: I ended up making it work with this code 

```.img-overlay {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/07/03/18/04/tech-1495181_1280.jpg");
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-12.5%, -20%);
  opacity: 0.2;
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  z-index: -1;
}```

Comment: Looks fine. Not sure why you need `translate` though. And `z-index` shouldn't be necessary if you put this element *before* another element.

Comment: I tried to add ::before and then remove the z-index, but for some reason the alignment is off. The only way i can align the image with the form box is to translate it onto it

Comment: Well, it depends where you want it to be displayed, but this `translate` looks a bit random. Have you tried `left: 0` and `top: 0`?

Comment: You probably have some padding there. If you use `position: absolute` without any actual coords, the element ends up sitting in it's default position, just detached from the flow.

Comment: done! also I posted another question showing the final code on codepen and if you knew how to refactor that, that would be great to hear your thoughts. If not, no worries